# Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc' in Angular 7 version

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, npm-install

I tried everything like `ng -update`, re-install angular, update TypeScript... I did everything that can be found around here but no luck, the error still persists.

Can anybody tell me what I missed so that I can overcome this issue?

Here is my `ng --version`:

```
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.3.10
Node: 12.15.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.10


Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core               0.8.9
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.10
@angular/cdk                       6.4.7
@angular/cli                       7.3.10
@angular/compiler                  6.0.9
@angular/language-service          4.4.7
@angular/material                  6.4.7
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   9.1.1
@schematics/angular                7.3.10
@schematics/update                 0.13.10
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.5.4
typescript                         3.8.3
webpack                            4.39.2
```

Comment: How do you actually get the error? during compile? what is in your package.json?

Comment: please update the question with the error you are facing....

Comment: @Felix ya I got this when  I run the command ng serve .Doing this its through error . I tried to install this with updated version but no luck.